# how could i remove a thin line between navigation bar and carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

screenshot: [thin white line between navbar and carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAvwn.png)

any ideas how could i remove that thin white line? my navbar is into a container & fixed top. My carousel is into another container-fluid.

Comment: Have you used a browsers developer tools to see if there is any margin on the navbar or carousel ? (I.e. Chrome dev tools, firebug etc.)

Comment: i tried chrome dev tools and i found a border 1px in the default navbar class. thanks for the tip.

Comment: can you post your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Make your container as in:

```
margin-top: 0 px;
```

Please put some code, so we can check it if you still have troubles :)